# can we use order by clause in view in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

can we use order by clause in view in sql server 2005?

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_authors 

    AS

    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * 

    FROM dbo.authors 
    Group by au_id
    ORDER BY au_fname
```

Comment: i am getting error like "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: Why do you want to use `order by` in the view? What do you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. You cannot use `order by` in the view itself to specify the order. You *can* use it for row selection, such as with `top 10`. From the [MSDN online docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> The `SELECT` clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
>      `COMPUTE` or `COMPUTE BY` clauses;
>      An `ORDER BY` clause, unless there is also a `TOP` clause in the select list of the `SELECT` statement <sup>(a)</sup>;
>      The `INTO` keyword;
>      The `OPTION` clause;
>      A reference to a temporary table or a table variable.
>
> <sup>(a)</sup> The `ORDER BY` clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the `TOP` clause in the view definition. The `ORDER BY` clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried, unless `ORDER BY` is also specified in the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_authors 

AS

SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * 

FROM dbo.authors 

WHERE au_fname='John'
```

However, `ORDER BY` is not valid. A view creates a dynamic result set which can then be queried in the same way as a table can. When querying a view you can then `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT au_fname
FROM vw_authors
ORDER BY au_fname
```

Comment: that is i already impletemted. but i am trying another way what i mentcation about

Comment: `ORDER BY` is valid in the OP's query because it defines what the `TOP 10 PERCENT` refers to. It shouldn't be taken as meaning that the results from a select against that view will be output in any particular order though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice [Overview of Views in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38560/Overview-of-View-in-SQL-Server-2005).  As noted in the article, the views can be indexed so that queries of the view can be efficiently ordered with an `ORDER BY`.  Also, see this [Microsoft article on indexed views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx).

The summary answer:  no, you can't use `ORDER BY` when creating a view, but you can index the view and use a fast `ORDER BY` on queries of that view.

Hope this helps.  Good luck with your project :-)